# Javascript Play Video on Mouse Hover (Multiple Videos)

Tags: javascript, video

I have the following JavaScript code that work great when I hover over a video. I like how the start and stop is broken into functions and it allows me to customize the hover play exactly how I want. However, this code only works on the first video on the page and I have several videos that are loaded on the page dynamically.

I would like to modify this code so that it will work on all videos on the page. I'm thinking that maybe the functions need to be called inside a loop? I'm not sure as I do not know JavaScript well, so any help on how to modify this code would would be much appreciated!

```
const video = document.querySelector("video");

function startPreview() {
  video.muted = true;
  video.currentTime = 5;
  video.playbackRate = 2.5;
  video.play();
}

function stopPreview() {
  video.currentTime = 5;
  video.playbackRate = 1;
  video.pause();
}

let previewTimeout = null;


video.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  startPreview();
  previewTimeout = setTimeout(stopPreview, 3000);
});

video.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  clearTimeout(previewTimeout);
  previewTimeout = null;
  stopPreview();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do event delegation to handle all videos. So:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('video') {
    // start playing
  }
});
```

More on the `matches()` method [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).

You would also modify the start and stop methods to take the video element as a parameter:

```
function startPreview(video) {
  video.muted = true;
  video.currentTime = 5;
  video.playbackRate = 2.5;
  video.play();
}
```

And pass them the `event.target`.